# Cases when Raoult's law is unsolvable

Tags: equilibrium, phase, vapor-pressure

#### Setup

Consider a closed binary mixture of known total molar composition $n_i$, held at volume $V$ and temperature $T$.  The equilibrium phase composition is determined by $\mu_i^{vap} = \mu_i^{liq}$. Assume the vapor is an ideal gas mixture, the liquid is an [ideal mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_solution), [Poynting's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_effect) is negligible, and $V_{liq} \ll V$. Then Raoult's law holds:

$$y_i P = x_i P_i^{sat}(T)\quad \tag{1}\label{1}$$

#### Simplify

For convenience, denote vapor quantity = $v_i$, liquid quantity = $l_i$, total quantity = $n_i=v_i+l_i$, and "saturation quantity" = $s_i=\frac{P_i^{sat}(T)\,V}{R T}$.  A closed system means $n_i$ are constant, and $s_i$ are constant at constant $T$.  For simplicity, choose units such that $R T = V = \sum_i n_i=1$, so that Raoult's law becomes

$$ n_i - l_i = s_i \frac {l_i}{\sum_i l_i} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

where $l_i$ are the only independent variables.  (The solution/result is **independent** of these choices. It holds for any Raoult's law system at constant $N, V, T$. It generalizes to infinite systems with fixed $\sum n_i/V$.)

#### Question

Eq. ($\ref{2}$) can be algebraically solved.  But it has no solution when $s_1>1$ and $s_1 - n_1 ≥ n_2 \frac{s_1}{s_2}$.  For example, if $s_1=2$ and $s_2=1/2$, then no solution exists when $n_2≤1/3$ ($x_2=y_1$ and $y_2=x_1$ at $\lim n_2\to \frac{1}{3}^+$).

This seems to predict that any generic species can form an uncondensable mixture if one is uncondensable (as a pure component), and there are few enough of the condensable species.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hi there, Alex, and welcome to the Chemistry StackExchange. It seems that you are trying to solve Raoult's Law in a manner that I have never seen before, and with quite a few non-standard variables. Might I suggest that you look into using the Antoine Equation to solve for the Saturation Pressure, of each species, as a function of Temperature. With this you can solve the Raoult's law equation as a function of Temperature, Pressure and either the gas or liquid fraction of species i. As for the prediction, I would not draw any conclusion about species based off of so many assumptions.

Comment: Thanks.  My only assumptions are ideality and constant T, V, and N.  That's a vessel with no reactions.  Everything else is just a choice of units to simplify Eq.1 into Eq.2.

Comment: I use an Antoine-like equation to obtain values for $P_i^{sat}(T)$.  But I'm still left to solve for the equilibrium values of $x_i$ and $y_i$.  That's nontrivial, because condensing any of species j changes the total amount of vapor & liquid, and thus affects every single $x_i$ and $y_i$.  Above I'm describing the algebraic solution, using different letters because standard ones overcomplicate the problem.

Comment: How do you justify this inequality: $s_1 - n_1 ≥ n_2 \frac{s_1}{s_2}$? What does it mean in plain words?

Comment: That inequality is the conditions for which simultaneously solving $n_1 - l_1 = s_1 l_1 / (l_1 + l_2)$ and $n_2 - l_2 = s_2 l_2 / (l_1 + l_2)$ has no solution for positive $l_1$ or $l_2$.  In plain words, Raoult's law cannot be satisfied when that inequality is true.

Comment: @alexchandel, it is most typical in a bicomponent system to first find the $x_1$, deduce $x_2$ as $x_2 = 1-x_1$, then apply Rault's Law to find the gas phase concentrations. A popular expansion of this is to condense the gas phase, collect it and measure the concentration of 1 and 2 in the collected liquid to find $y_1$ and $y_2$ and apply the activity modified Rault's law $y_iP=\gamma_ix_iP_i^{sat}(T)$. This renders activity coefficents which can then be compared to those predicted by tabulated van Laar coefficents.

Comment: So to say that you still have to solve for $x_i$ or $y_i$ of your system is entirely correct - this is the intended use of Rault's Law.

Comment: Perhaps towards this point it would be better to define your non-standard variables of $l_i$ and $v_i$ in more explicit terms. As you have it written, the only sensible unit for these would be in terms of moles, and they could be re-written as $l_i = n_{liq}x_i = n_{liq,i}$, and $v_i = n_{vap}y_i = n_{vap,i}$, where $\sum_i x_i = 1$, $\sum_i y_i = 1$, and $n_{total} = n_{vap} + n_{liq}$. Using this method, you can keep track of both the phase and the component of each variable

Comment: I think that a large amount of my confusion about your approach is in how and why you are defining a "saturation quantity". As per your definition from the ideal gas law, and Rault's law, you can find that $s_i=\frac{n_{vap}y_i}{x_i}=\frac{n_{vap,i}}{x_i}$. This has no intuitive meaning to me, and as I have never seen such an approach, I am unsure as to why you are using it.

Comment: That said, if you consider $s_i=\frac{n_{vap}y_i}{x_i}$, given the system you described a solution exists at $n_{vap}=0.682$, $x_1 = 0.088$ and $y_1 = 0.279$. Note that $n_{vap}$ does not change between the two calculations, as it represents the total quantity of gas phase molecules. If you need a derivation of this, I an provide one.

Comment: After defining fugacity and activity coefficients, to predict a mixture's equilibrium I still have to simultaneously solve $\mu_i^L=\mu_i^V$ (i.e. Raoult's law for ideal gases + ideal mixtures) either numerically or algebraically.  I changed from $\{x_i, y_i, P_i^{sat}, R, T, V, n_{liq}, n_{vap}\}$ to $\{n_i, l_i, s_i\}$ to eliminate redundant terms in Eq (1) for the latter purpose.  (Intuitively, $s_i$ is to a species' vapor quantity what $P_i^{sat}$ is to its vapor pressure.)

Comment: The algebraic solution to Eq (2) was bound by that inequality.  $n_{vap}=0.682$, $x_1 = 0.088$, $y_1 = 0.279$ does solve the system, but it doesn't satisfy the inequality ($s_1-n_1 ≈ 1.94$, but $n_2\frac{s_1}{s_2} ≈ 3.14$), so no surprises there.

Comment: Try to find a solution to Raoult's law when $s_1=2$, $s_2=0.5$, and $n_2 = 1/4$.  (If units are a must, assume $\frac{P_1^{sat}(T) V}{R T} = 2 \mathrm{mol}$ and $\frac{P_2^{sat}(T) V}{R T} = 0.5 \mathrm{mol}$, and introduce $0.25 \mathrm{mol}$ of species #2 and $0.75 \mathrm{mol}$ of species #1 into an empty, rigid vessel held at constant T.)  None exists.

Comment: @alexchandel With this setup, you are only defining component 1 has 4x the saturation pressure of component 2, and that component 1 is present in 3x the quantity. There is no reason that Raoult's law is cannot be solved for such a system. I think you went wrong with an assumption somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided a source for your definition of $s_i$, I shall redefine it in terms of Raoult's Law and the Ideal Gas Law. To do this, we shall first take Raoult's Law and solve for $P$.

$$\begin{align}y_iP&=x_iP_i^{sat}(T)\\P&=\frac{x_iP_i^{sat}(T)}{y_i}\end{align}$$

we shall then take this form, and plug it into the ideal gas law, considering only the gas phase of the equilibrium system. Note that because the system is at equilibrium, $P_{bulk}=P_{liq}=P_{vap}$ and $T_{bulk}=T_{liq}=T_{vap}$. If the volume of the liquid phase is assumed to be significantly lower than that of the vapor, then $V_{bluk}=V_{vap}$. After plugging in this, we will then work towards the form of $s_i$ as shown.

$$\begin{align}P_{vap}V_{vap}&=n_{vap}RT_{vap}\\PV&=n_{vap}RT\\n_{vap}&=\frac{PV}{RT}\\n_{vap}&=\frac{x_iP_i^{sat}(T)}{y_i}\frac{V}{RT}\\\frac{n_{vap}y_i}{x_i}&=\frac{P_i^{sat}(T)V}{RT}\end{align}$$

From this, and the definition of $s_i$ as you stated, we can show that

$$s_i=\frac{P_i^{sat}(T)V}{RT}=\frac{n_{vap}y_i}{x_i}$$

which is subject only to the reasonable assumptions of ideality as stated above, and the bounds per the definition of each term. Namely, $\left\{P_i^{sat}(T),V,T\right\}$ must be positive, real numbers and that $\left\{x_i,y_i\right\}$ must be positive, real numbers with bounds of $\left\lbrack0,1\right\rbrack$.

No further inequalities are required to describe the system.

To solve such a system, you would then set up a system of equations and numerically backsolve for an answer, in terms $n_{vap},x_{i},y_{i}$. For example you might feed a set of equations the seed values of $n_{vap}=1$ and $x_i=.5=y_i$ such as seen below, then optimize your values to minimize the error between the calculated and target values.

[image: Seed Values]

The above seed values could then optimize to a particular solution that looks like. Note that this does not represent the whole of the solution space.

[image: Calculated Values]

If you wish to further control where your particular solution ends up, you can restrict the solution space by hold one of the values to be a known constant. Below is one such example as described per your comments.

[image: Error values]

In this case, it is not possible to find a reasonable solution, as $n_{vap}=0.25~\text{mol}$ lies outside the solution space for this system of equations. Without going too heavily into the derivation, it can generally be stated that this value is a bit too low to garuntee that you will be able to find a solution. This more says that if you had this system, it would likely evolve off more of its liquid into the gas phase <s>at</s> *in order to reach* equilibrium than it says the system could not exist, though yours is not an unreasonable reading of the result.

A good rule of thumb for this would be that you can expect to find a reasonable solution for $\left\{x_i,y_i\right\}$ for any system in which $s_1 \leq n_{vap} \leq s_2$ holds, however this is by far the most complicated way to solve out this system of equations. A simpler approach to this would be to hold either $x_i$ or $y_i$ constant to restrict the solution space, as any constant value on the bounds of $\left\lbrack0,1\right\rbrack$, as already assumed will garuntee a unique solution to the system of equations.

Comment: My question isn't how to solve Raoult's law; for < 5 components, at constant $V, T$, & $V_{liq} \ll V$, Raoult's law has (if any exists) an exact algebraic solution for a given $N_i$, which numerical methods approximate.  I'm talking about equilibrium behavior when Raoult's law is unsolvable.  "This more says that if you had this system, it would likely _evolve off more_ of its liquid into the gas phase _at equilibrium_" — then that isn't equilibrium.

Comment: _"…it can generally be stated that this value is a bit too low to garuntee that you will be able to find a solution."_  — The proof of that is the premise of the question.  _"…you can expect to find a reasonable solution for $\left\{x_i,y_i\right\}$ for any system in which $s_1\leq n_{vap}\leq s_2$ holds"_ — Not so: take $s_1=0.5$ mol, $s_2=2$ mol, & begin with $n_1 = 0.25$ mol, $n_2 = 0.75$ mol ($\to n_{vap}≤1$ mol).  No solution exists for any $n_{liq}>0$, and limiting $f_i^{liq}>f_i^{vap}$ imply $n_{liq}=0,n_{vap}=1$ mol at equilibrium.  So $s_1\leq n_{vap}\leq s_2$ with no solution.

Comment: _"this is by far the most complicated way to solve out this system of equations."_  — How else would you determine the equilibrium phase compositions of a given closed mixture at a constant $V, T$?  _"hold either $x_i$ or $y_i$ constant to restrict the solution space…, as already assumed will garuntee a unique solution to the system of equations."_ — Fixing $y_1$ and $y_2$ (or $x_1$ and $x_2$) is incompatible with finding the equilibrium of a given closed binary mixture at constant $V, T$, as solution space is already zero-dimensional.

Comment: In regards to the second comment, note that $n_{vap} \neq n_{vap,i}$, and is the *total* number of moles in the gas phase from all $i$ species, and therefore must be the same of both species. If you hold $n_{vap}=0.75$ a solution exists at $x_1=0.167$ and $y_1=0.444$.

Comment: In regards to the third comment - I was assuming that $n_{vap}$ would be able to be modulated by changing the pressure of the system, but after looking over your most recent revision, I see that this is not the case, which means that $n_{vap}$ would be held constant under the ideal gas law and the definition of the system.

Comment: With that said, *yes*, it would be fair to say that if you are holding, $P, V, T$ and therefore $n_{vap}$ as being constant, then you *will not* always be able to design a system such that a target $s_1$ and $s_2$ values are met.